# Como a interpretação do código HTML funciona?

Tags: html, parser

Estou fazendo uma árvore para derivar um código HTML. E estou tratando alguns casos particulares. E um desses casos é justamente quando alguém abre uma tag e não a fecha:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div>
        Hello World!!
      </div>
      Hello People!!
  </body>
</html>
```

Já estudei compiladores na universidade, porém não entendo como a interpretação do html funciona. No caso ao qual mostrei falta fechar um `</div>` antes do `</body>`. Abrindo a página e olhando o código vi que a página insere um `</div>` antes do `</body`. Mas o que fez a página adicionar o `</div>` ali e não antes do texto: `Hello People!!`. Foi o fato de `</body>` ser chamada e ainda o primeiro `<div>` ainda não ser fechado?

Código da página gerado:

```html
<html><head></head><body>
    <div>
      <div>
        Hello World!!
      </div>
      Hello People!!
  
</div></body></html>
```

A algum nome especifico para a interpretação do código html?

Comment: Interessante, eu já tinha notado que o próprio Browser fecha algumas tags, na verdade segundo a documentação W3C várias tag não precisam ser fechadas, como as `<p>` etc, Mas como o browser "acertou" onde fechar a div ali depois do texto realmente não sei explicar...

Comment: Já li sobre isso em algum lugar. Mas acho que os navegadores modernos possuem uma tecnologia que corrige automaticamente várias coisas.

Comment: Mas creio que o fechamento da div antes do `</body>` se dá porque ele desconsidera nós de texto. Faz mais sentido fechar o elemento após todos os nós de texto, pq supõe-se que os textos fazem parte da div.

Comment: Ou melhor, ele vai fechar a tag onde fecha o seu pai, no caso, o body.

Comment: Também não sei dizer exatamente qual a implementação interna, mas mantendo um contador de tags abertas e vendo por sequencia de abertura e fecho, ao chegar ao fecho de body, o `</body>` o browser sabe que está um div por fechar e que tem de ser fechado antes, e então opta por fechar ali pois dali para a frente não pode estar para ser correto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você misturou muitas coisas na sua pergunta:

- "código HTML", o correto é documentação de HTML.
- compiladores interpretam lexemas e não uma documentação!

> Sobre a pergunta em si, precisa ou não ser fechado?

Você sempre precisa colocar as tags, não só porque nas boas práticas dizem para você fazer isso, mas porque isso depende do navegador que está utilizando, que por sua vez faz a contagem de tags e adiciona o que está faltando.

- Regras da W3C quando não precisa fechar a tag (mas como dito anteriomente, nem todo navegador vai seguir essas regras):
  https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/syntax.html#optional-tags
- Uma leitura mais complexa sobre as tags:
  https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/syntax.html#writing-html-documents-elements

Comment: Entendi seu ponto, eu sei que html não é uma LP. Mas gostaria de entender como o navegador "entende" essa linguagem.

Comment: Hudson e pq se eu colocar `<div> lalala <p>fsdfsd` a `<div>` fecha no lugar certo, mas seu eu colocar `<p>fsdfsd <div>lalala` primeiro fecha o `<p>` e depois fecha a `<div>`, o esperado seria a tag `<p>` fechar depois da `</div>` e isso não acontece... mas ficou `<p></p><div></div>`

Comment: @hugocsl depende do navegador, na documentacao oficial vc precisa sempre fechar o link esta acima.

Comment: @ViniciusMorais cada navegador tem sua engine. Vc pode criar sua engine em c++, c#, java...

Comment: O FF nem se quer fechou as tags, e o Edge se comportou igual ao Chrome, se for  `<div> lalala <p>fsdfsd` fica `<div> lalala <p>fsdfsd</p> </div>` mas se for assim: `<p>fsdfsd <div>lalala` o resultado é assim: `<p>fsdfsd</p> <div>lalala</div>`  Tanto no Chrome quando Edge, No FF como falei na fecha...

Comment: @hugocsl por padrao do w3 vai ser antes da proxima tag, a tag que esta faltando ser fechada vai ser fechada antes de abri a proxima tag. com exemplos: https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/syntax.html#optional-tags

Comment: Sim isso já era claro, a dúvia é pq o P ele fecha de um jeito e a Div ele fecha de outro. o P parece que ele fecha no fim do próprio conteúdo, já a div parece que ele fecha de baixo para cima. Aqui que é a dúvida, basta vc testa com esse código simples ai que comentei e vc vai ver que o comportamento de um e de outro é diferente...

Comment: Como eu disse <P> nem deveria fechar de acordo com w3 a regra para fechar 'e que a proxima tag seja uma dessas:  `address, article, aside, blockquote, details, div, dl, fieldset, figcaption, figure, footer, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hr, main, menu, nav, ol, p, pre, section, table, ou ul` o que acontece que o navegador esta fazendo esse trabalho.

Comment: e mesmo assim isso nao garante que navegadores criado por terceiros reproduzam essas regras na integra.

Comment: @hugocsl creio que seja porque a div não pode ficar dentro de um <p>, por isso o <p> é fechado antes da abertura da div.

Comment: como eu disse acima o <p> vai ser fechado antes pq na lista citada acima a div esta inclusa.

Comment: ja quando comeca com "address", "article", "aside", "blockquote", "center", "details", "dir", "div", "dl", "fieldset", "figcaption", "figure", "footer", "header", "main", "menu", "nav", "ol", "p", "section", "summary", "ul" o p fica dentro. regras das w3.

Answer (score 2):

Então, não quer dizer que se o navegador fechou as TAGS, ele as fechou em lugar certo.
Já tive sérios problemas com esquecimento de tags no início da minha tragetória, principalmente com divs. A verdade é que se você não fechar da forma correta, provavelmente seu código não irá funcionar como você gostaria, apesar de "parecer" que está correto, não funcionará corretamente.

**Obs.:** Para códigos simples pode até funcionar, mas quando você tem muitos códigos complexos, com certeza que não.

**Respondendo a sua pergunta:** a forma com que o navegador fecha acredito eu ser semelhante a forma que as IDES de desenvolvimento sugerem ao programador, é a programação do navegador, foi feito para assimilar isto, mas não faz milagre.

**Isto se chama de Tolerância a erros dos navegadores.**

Você nunca recebe um erro "Sintaxe inválida" em uma página HTML. Os navegadores consertam qualquer conteúdo inválido e prosseguem suas funções.

**Tome este HTML como exemplo:**

```html
<html>
  <mytag>
  </mytag>
  <div>
  <p>
  </div>
    Really lousy HTML
  </p>
</html>
```

Devo ter violado um milhão de regras ("**mytag**" não é uma tag padrão, aninhamento incorreto dos elementos "p" e "div" e mais), mas o navegador ainda exibe o conteúdo corretamente. Portanto, grande parte do código do analisador é feito para consertar erros de autores HTML.
[Você pode saber mais sobre como os navegadores funcionam neste link](https://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/#Browsers_error_tolerance)